# ActionsScript 3 Event Listener Not Executing Function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, events, listener, trace

The code below doesn't seem to work as expected, I'm not even seeing the trace statement, but I receive no errors. I'm extremely confused!

```
keyboardMC.button0MC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Button0);

function Button0(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    trace('0');
}
```

I should also mention that any other code that I put into the function is not executed.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Is `keyboardMC.button0MC` visible on the stage with no mouse enabled object above it in the display list?  If you set `buttonMode = true` on `button0MC` does the mouse cursor change to a hand?

Comment: @JasonSturges `keyboardMC.button0MC` is visible with no mouse enabled object above it from what I can tell, what's the display list? I've already set `buttonMode = true` on `button0MC` and I do see the mouse cursor change to a hand.

Comment: Are you running debug mode, if not you won't be seeing the trace statements output.

Comment: @shaunhusain Debug mode is on and I have just put a trace statement at the beginning of the code to test that.

Comment: well your function naming is unconventional should be something like button_clickHandler, though I don't think there's anything actually technically wrong with your naming choice it might be worth changing, next thing I would try is drop a debug point on the line where the listener is added here or put a trace statement there to be sure the listener is being registered

Comment: Next step after that would be to add a listener to the stage and check the event.target when you try to click the button/movieclip

Comment: @shaunhusain Could you provide some example code for that please, I've not come across a debug point before.

Comment: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html <-- this has the info you need, just need to double click in the gray area to the left of the code to make a breakpoint

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks for the link, I've bookmarked it so I can take a look in the morning since it's early morning here and don't think I'm thinking straight with the code anymore, hopefully some rest will help. Haha. Thank you for the help and I'll let you know if it worked!

Comment: @KristianMatthews no problem let me know how it goes, I can test here too, just don't normally run Flash IDE myself, personally a much bigger fan of Flex/FlashBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be working if as Jason Sturges said it's on top of the [Display List](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/). Basically check if something is overlayed on that movieclip, it won't take events.

What shaumhusain meant was to do it like this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickHandler);
function OnClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   trace(e.target.name);
}
```

Also check if the parent of that movieclip is mouseEnabled, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I used your code, thank you so much, it immediately made me realise what the problem was I had `buttonMode = true` and `mouseChildren = false` both on the `keyboardMC` and not the `button0MC`, it's working perfectly now so thank you.